# Is there any benefit to having foil cards?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

Foil cards appear to be identical to normal cards, except they have a distracting moving rainbow thing on them. I received some from promotional codes. Is there any gameplay benefit to having foil versions of cards, or are they just an artifact from the physical game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foil cards are simply cosmetic items, and do not grant any extra gameplay benefits in game.

Comment: Lies! The shiny distracts your opponents at critical decision making moments! Shiny! SHINY!

Comment: All we'll need to do is get foil cards, and there's no way anyone can possibly win! Muahahahahahah!

Answer (score 2):

no, there is totally no difference between normal and foil cards, except for the looks. In real life the foil cards normally cost a bit more than normal ones, because they are "fancier"